# On Android, absolute parent with border-radius does not hide corner of relative child image

Tags: android, jquery, css, image

I have a div positioned as relative and inside a image positioned as absolute, with a zoom effect on hover. The parent div has a border radius which cuts the left corners of the image (child) just fine in Chrome, Firefox but on Android is not working.

The html and css must remain the same and somehow make it show properly on Android phones - on Iphone i did not try since i don't have one.
Any solutions that i have found on this website do not work in my case so i hope that anyone will have a valid solution. Thanks

The structure is

```css
body {
    background-color:grey;
}
.inner-container {
    width:100%;
    height:160px;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    z-index:30;
}
.listing-thumb {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 214px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.listing-thumb img {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    border: 0 none;
    bottom: 0;
    float: none;
    left: -50%;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -50%;
    top: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    -ms-transform:scale(1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    transform:scale(1);
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.listing-thumb img:hover {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-transform:scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="listing-photo"> <a class="listing-thumb" title="" href="">
            <img alt="" title="" src="http://www.mercedes-benz.ro/content/media_library/hq/hq_mpc_reference_site/passenger_cars_ng/new_cars/models/e-class/_w212/pad_11-2012/core_navigation/mercedes-benz-e-class-w212_model_navigation_960x298_11-2012_jpg.object-Single-MEDIA.tmp/mercedes-benz-e-class-w212_model_navigation_960x298_11-2012.jpg">
        </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="listing-photo"> <a class="listing-thumb" title="" href="">
            <img alt="" title="" src="http://s1.cdn.autoevolution.com/images/news/2014-mercedes-cla-45-amg-first-photos-leaked-photo-gallery-56630_1.jpg">
        </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="listing-photo"> <a class="listing-thumb" title="" href="">
            <img alt="" title="" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1881059795/Star_Carbon_Background_400x400.gif">
        </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you can use as demo in Android native browser http://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/7mcxcdv8/7/

Answer (score 0):

Which browser did you try on Android? It might be a browser problem.

Comment: The default browser. Not chrome or firefox or opera.

Comment: So other browsers on android work? 
That means its a browser problem since you are using **CSS3** attributres like `transform` and `backface-visibility`.

Comment: The issue comes from parent div as relative and child as absolute. If i place them as static, the issue will be gone but i will break my layout/functionality. As for transform not supported - http://caniuse.com/#search=transform - so it is not true